# Sailsjs Barrels fixtures required associations

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sails.js, fixtures

I'm building Sails.js application and refactoring my tests to use Barrels fixtures. One of my model has required association. [I read the instructions in Barrels repo](https://github.com/bredikhin/barrels) about required associations. Below is my code which I use to load the fixtures. I keep getting an error about not passing Project to Activity (Activity model has a required association to Project).

```
var barrels = Promise.promisifyAll(new Barrels(process.cwd() + '/test/fixtures'));

return barrels.populateAsync(['project', 'integrations', 'user']).then(function() {
  return barrels.populateAsync(['activity']);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I tried to switch automatic association off in second populate and it looks like that Activities are created but their project field will get plain number defined in fixtures. I don't really trust it being correct always even though I use sails-disk for testing db.

So what is the problem here? Below is same code as one above but with callbacks wrapped into promise and auto-association switched off:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
  var barrels = new Barrels(process.cwd() + '/test/fixtures');

  barrels.populate(['project', 'integrations', 'user'], function(err) {
    barrels.populate(['activity'], function(err) {
      resolve();
    }, false);
  });
});
```